# How can I open a window using dynamic url whose end query is ":id"in Angular 9?

Tags: angular, routes

I want to open a dynamic url which contains ":id" at the end where I also want to pass the query in ":id" . Thanking you in anticipation.
The url "/search/:id" should contain the value stored in "query" variable.

**component.ts file**

```
     this.query="world";
     let url = "/search/:id";
     window.open(url, "_self");
```

**App-routing.module.ts**

```
 {
    path: "news/search/:id",
    component: SearchComponent
 }
```

Comment: what do you mean by `query` variable? you mean `query parameter?`

Comment: Yeah. It meant query parameter. My bad.

Comment: how do you want the url to look like?

Comment: url should be something like "search/world" or "search/earth" etc. The last one will be the value set in parameter "query"

Answer (score 0):

By using routerlink, take a look at this documentation: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink
And variables coming in from your ts file + service.